# Error - redigo.Scan: Cannot convert from Redis bulk string to *string

Tags: go, redis, redigo

I have a `struct` like that

```
type User struct {
    Nickname  *string `json:"nickname"`
    Phone     *string `json:"phone"`
}
```

Values ​​are placed in redis with `HMSET` command. (values ​​can be nil)

Now I'm trying to `scan` values ​​into a structure:

```
values, err := redis.Values(Cache.Do("HMGET", "key", "nickname", "phone" )

var usr User

_, err := redis.Scan(values, &usr.Nickname, &usr.Phone)
```

But I get an error

> redigo.Scan: cannot assign to dest 0: cannot convert from Redis bulk
>   string to *string

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Scan documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Scan) says:

> The values pointed at by dest must be an integer, float, boolean, string, []byte, interface{} or slices of these types.

The application passes a pointer to a `*string` to the function.  A `*string` is not one of the supported types.

There are two approaches for fixing the problem. The first is to allocate `string` values and pass pointers to the allocated `string` values to Scan:

```
usr := User{Nickname: new(string), Phone: new(string)}
_, err := redis.Scan(values, usr.Nickname, usr.Phone)
```

The second approach is to change the type of the struct fields to `string`:

```
type User struct {
    Nickname  string `json:"nickname"`
    Phone     string `json:"phone"`
}

...

var usr User
_, err := redis.Scan(values, &usr.Nickname, &usr.Phone)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#hdr-Executing_Commands) it says that `[]byte` is type for bulk string, not `*string`. You have two options here:

1. change the particular field type to `[]byte`
2. or use temporary variable with `[]byte` type on the scan, then after the data retrieved store it to the struct's field

Comment: A primary purpose of `Scan` is to convert bulk strings (represented as `[]byte`) to other Go types including `string`.  The problem is that `*string` is not a supported destination type, not that there's a mismatch with the representation of bulk strings.